# SemanticUI scrolling dropdown on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown, semantic-ui

I have problem with Semantic-UI when I scroll page. If I start scrolling and I touch dropdown, the whole content is showing.

I only want to open dropdown when I click on it, not even my finger is going through it.

Try to scroll this page on mobile: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Comment: Some images would help to better understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

Just unbind **touchstart** event, like:

```
    $('.ui.dropdown').unbind('touchstart');
```